# Getting PostgreSQL to work with Python/Django (lack of pg_config)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ide, terminal

I'm brand new to web development and have decided to learn Python/Django and using PostgreSQL. I'm currently using a MacbookPro (OS X 10.9.1). I'm following along with [this guide](http://www.djangobook.com/). Things were chugging along just fine until [chapter 5 (databases)](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html).

In the instructions leading up to table 5-2, I run `python manage.py shell` and I get the error message: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2`. According to table 5-2:

> [I] haven’t installed the appropriate database-specific adapter (e.g., psycopg or MySQLdb). Adapters > are not bundled with Django, so it’s [my] responsibility to download and install them on [my] own.

That's a simple enough problem to understand. I thought I had installed psycopg2, but I went to install it again (this would replay itself over several times). I literally tried installing psycopg2 in every possible way according to [their official page](http://initd.org/psycopg/install/).

I tried using `python setup.py install`, `easy_install psycop2`, and `pip` (and all with their `sudo` variations as well) and in all instances, `pg_config` could not be found.

I looked for `pg_config` and found a file similarly-named within Postgres.app, but pointing to this file did absolutely nothing to change the problem of the missing `pg_config`.

Some instructions online suggested that this was the result of not having PostgreSQL installed, but I am absolutely sure PostgreSQL is installed (via instructions [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/)).

There was also another instruction suggesting that this was due to Xcode not being installed. However, in my case, Xcode is installed.

I'm out of ideas as to why this could possibly be happening. I realize that this question has been asked multiple times before, but I've followed all the instructions to the letter without a satisfactory result. What is going on?

**As an aside**, doing all this back-and-forth in Terminal is really time-consuming. I'd love it if someone could recommend me some Python/Django IDE and PostgreSQL software with GUI (preferably one that can import CSVs or more) that work seamlessly with one another. They don't have to be free, but any costs should be paired with good value.

Comment: I use komodo IDE: http://komodoide.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

`pg_config` is a program that exists to tell other programs how PostgreSQL is installed on your machine; it's often needed when you compile things that connect to Postgres (like psycopg2).

If you know where your pg_config is, you can put it on your PATH:

```
$ PATH=/path/to/your/pg_config:$PATH pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: I found a file named `pg_config` (in /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/), but I'm not sure if that's the right `pg_config`. I tried your `PATH` code from above but it comes back as: `Error: Unable to find 'pg_config' file in '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/'` – this is happening even as I'm looking at a file named `pg_config` in Finder. **P.S.** This is related to what I've written above as well.